# Prevent caching for a single page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, caching

I am working with a multi-page form that requires a unique identifier. The object is created in the first page and updated in subsequent pages. Currently if a user goes back with the browser's back button and resubmits the first page it will error out because an object has already been created with that identifier. I would like to prevent caching so that I can make a patch/put request if the first page is revisited. I am using

```
def prevent_caching
  response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
  response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
  response.headers["Expires"] = "0"
end
```

When I was working in Chrome the page was being resubmitted (even before adding this bit of code), but I added this after seeing that Safari was not resubmitting the page. It doesn't seem to be preventing caching. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm calling this method as a before action on the method that will render the page. Could that be part of the problem?